# Calling values from a dictionary (Django)

Tags: django, dictionary

I am fairly new to Django and I am having trouble getting values to load into the HTML from the dictionary generated in the `models.py` that looks like this:

```
>>> generic_id = Generic.objects.get(pk=127)
>>> dict = generic_id._get_dict()
>>> dict  
[{'field__name':'key1', 'value_char':'value1a', 'value_num':'value1'},{'field__name':'key2', 'value_char':'value2a', 'value_num':'value2'},{'field__name':'key3', 'value_char':'value3a', 'value_num':'value3'},{'field__name':'key4', 'value_char':'value4a', 'value_num':'value4'}]
>>> dict[2]['value_num']  
Decimal('value2')
>>> dict[3]['value_char']
'value3a'
```

The HTML table looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Description1</td><td>{{value1}}</td>
    <td>Description2</td><td>{{value2}}</td>
    <td>Description3</td><td>{{value3a}}</td>
    <td>Description4</td><td>{{value4}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: {{ generic.name }}</td>
    <td>E-mail: {{ generic.email }}</td>
    <td>State: {{ generic.state }}
</table>
```

The code in the `views.py` right now looks like this:

```
def query_test(request, generic_id):
    try:
        a = Generic_table.objects.get(pk=generic_id)
    except Generic_table.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    t = loader.get_template('query_test.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
             'generic' : a, })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Can someone give me some suggestions as to how to (and efficiently) get the appropriate values from the dictionary into the generated HTML?

Comment: What problem are you actually having? Can you show us your template? Can you show us any errors you are encountering?

Comment: I don't know how to set it up.  I am unsure how to get the dict values from my models.py file to be processed in the view and then rendered in the template.  Right now the html looks like a table that says "Description 1 {{value1}}", etc.

Comment: I know how to get it to work with simpler dictionaries ["first_name":"Joe", "last_name":"Smith"].  I just can't figure out this more complex dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what your objects look like from your model, and your template, I would suggest trying this:

assuming:

```
a = Generic.objects.get(pk=generic_id)
# a == {'field__name':'key1', 'value_char':'value1a', 'value_num':'value1'}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def query_test(request, generic_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(Generic, pk=generic_id)

    return render_to_response("query_test.html", a, 
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

query_test.html

```
Name: {{field__name}}
Char: {{value_char}}
Num : {{value_num}}
```

Your view doesn't show that you are expecting more than one object, since you look for an id, so your template would end up formatting just one object.

**Edit**: In case you are trying to display a list of results

views.py might look something like this:

```
def query_test(request, generic_id=None):
    if generic_id is not None:
        a = Generic.objects.filter(pk=generic_id)
    else:
        a = Generic.objects.all()

    c = {'generic': a}

    # add some extra values
    c['value1'] = "I am value1"

    # add a whole dictionary of other values
    c.update({'value2': "yay val2", 'value3a': 3, 'value4': "I am 4"})

    return render_to_response("query_test.html", c, 
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And your template something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Description1</td><td>{{value1}}</td>
    <td>Description2</td><td>{{value2}}</td>
    <td>Description3</td><td>{{value3a}}</td>
    <td>Description4</td><td>{{value4}}</td>
</tr>
{% for item in generic %}
    <tr>
        <td>Name: {{item.field__name}}</td>
        <td>Char: {{item.value_char}}</td>
        <td>Num : {{item.value_num}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

**Edit2**: Addressing the strange object you are sending to your template

Based on your updated question... That is not a dictionary. Its a list of dictionaries, and Its really strange the way you are pulling that data from the single model instance. But assuming that is what you really really want, you have a number of options..

1) Fix that data object BEFORE sending it to the template. I have no idea if you want all the elements in that list, or just a specific item.

```
not_a_generic_id = Generic.objects.get(pk=127)
not_a_dict = not_a_generic_id._get_dict()
dict_that_I_actually_want = not_a_dict[1]
return render_to_response("query_test.html", dict_that_I_actually_want)
```

2) Send that entire list to the template and loop over each item, and then access the values:

*views.py*

```
not_a_generic_id = Generic.objects.get(pk=127)
not_a_dict = not_a_generic_id._get_dict()
c = {"still_not_a_dict": not_a_dict}
return render_to_response("query_test.html", c)
```

*template.html*

```
<table>
{% for actual_dict in still_not_a_dict %}
    <tr>
        <td>Name: {{actual_dict.field__name}}</td>
        <td>Char: {{actual_dict.value_char}}</td>
        <td>Num : {{actual_dict.value_num}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

3) Even though the template does not let you actually access numeric indexes of lists because you are suppost to sort that data out yourself in the view...if you insist on accessing a specific index of that list in the template, do the same as #2 for the views.py, but:

*template.html*

```
{% for actual_dict in still_not_a_dict %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
        {{actual_dict.value_char}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The two types of methods you explained are the ones I have figured out how to do.  Maybe I'm not explaining it well, but where I am having the trouble is getting the values: value1, value2, value3a, value4 into the template.   I am only looking at one record, but it has a large number of methods that hit other tables.  So the dict is a dictionary of records from another table that are being brought in.  I edited the template on the question to include other variables I am loading.

Comment: @David__ - Ok, I just updated my second example section in the view to show you how to add more arbitrary values to the context before sending it to the template

Comment: When I try the dict that you create with c, it works fine.  But when I use the dictionary that I have [{xx:x1, yy:y1, zz:z1},{aa:a1,bb:b1, cc:c1}], I get an error that the list indice must be an integer.  Its like I have dicitonaries, within a dictionary.  I added to my original post some of the results from the pythons shell of what I need to do there to get the results I need.  Any ideas how to use the working python dict[int][value_xx], into the django template language.

Comment: @David__ -  That is not a dictionary. Its a list of dictionaries. You are getting that error because a list must be accessed by numeric indexes. At this point I have to ask why you are accessing the values of this model in such a fashion? Im not sure why you require calling _get_dict() on this single model instance? Are you ABSOLUTELY sure you are getting the values from your Generic result in the proper way? If so, you have multiple options... I will again, update my answer...

Comment: I finally figured that out and created a function that works around that problem.  Thank you for all the help.